# Linq How to deflate list of class/self join

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of the following class

```
class testdata {
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string[] values { get; set; }
}
```

how to perform join such that I get list of code and values, i.e values will repeat with every code, e.g if there are two items in list like

```
1."code1",{"value1","value2"}

2."code2",{"value1","value2","value3"}
```

I want the final to be in format like

```
Code1,Value1

code1,Value2

Code2,value1

code3,value2

code3,value3
```

I want to achieve it via LINQ and anonymous class, I am able to do it with loop and by creating a class as per final structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myList.SelectMany(td => td.values.Select(v => new { td.code, v } ))
```

`SelectMany` says "take many IEnumerables and concatenate their elements into a single IEnumerable"

`td` is a single element in your list.  It is a single instance of `testdata`

So now you can do a `Select` over `td.values` to create the individual anonymous objects.  `Select` will return an IEnumerable, but wrapped inside a `SelectMany`, many instances of`IEnumerable<anonymous object>` will be flattened into a single `IEnumerable<anonymous object>`

Comment: Thanks, It is giving the intended result, Can you explain the working little bit?

Comment: @Ratna - just edited the post with more details.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            List<TestData> testData = new List<TestData>() {
                new TestData() { code = "Code1", values = new string[] {"Value1","Value2"}},
                new TestData() { code = "Code2", values = new string[] {"value1"}},
                new TestData() { code = "code3", values = new string[] {"value2","value3"}}
            };

            var results = testData.Select(x => x.values.Select(y => new { code = x.code, value = y })).SelectMany(y => y).ToList();
```